# Picard–Lindelöf theorem in real world applications

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

Okay guys, so my question is easy. Is there any applications of the Picard–Lindelöf theorem in physics or other real world applications?
I'm asking because I see that I have a whole course ahead about existence and uniqueness of solutions of differential equations, so I need an extra motivation to study it.
My first assumption is that if a differential equation pops out in some model of the world, it should have a unique solution, and the theorem would be useless for physicist.
But I hope things are more interesting and strange. I don't know, in quantum mechanics maybe?

Comment: The Picard-Lindelöff theorem does not only give existence and uniqueness, but also a scheme how to approximate the solution. It does not get much better :) differential equations are everywhere in physics. You want to describe a system and mostly you end with either an ordinary differential equation (ODE) or a partial differential equation. What would you like to be more interesting? If you mean ODE's, then surely there is a lot of interesting stuff happening. Picard-Lindelöf have regularity assumptions that are not always satisfied and then things start to get much harder/more interesting.

Comment: PL is a theorem which guarantees the existence and uniqueness of certain kinds of IVPs. So whenever you encounter such an IVP, you now that it has a solution first of all (which clears out the possibility of working on an impossible problem) and that once you find this solution you don't need to look for anything else. This theorem works as a basis for other existence and uniqueness theorems for different kinds of IVPs, but I would say that the importance of PL in physics is rather due to the importance of differential equations in physics, so you should think about that instead.

Comment: I can imagine a whole course just on Picard Lindelof. Are they discussing existence and uniqueness of PDE?

Comment: How do you know that your *mathematical model* of the physical situation really behaves like you would expect it to (according to physical intuition), unless you have some mathematical theorems to justify it?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven, that's what I would like to know, examples of the physical world that don't satisfy the assumptions of the theorem. I think that would be really interesting.

Comment: But @StefanOctavian, every problem of the physical world that come to my mind in which a differential equation pops out, it will have a solution.

Comment: @HansLundmark that's true !! If I have a model of the physical world which gives me a differential equation with no unique solutions, that would be really strange and I would discard it. Thanks! So satisfying PL assumptions would indicate that the model is not too bad.

Comment: @ArcticChar not yet, and I don't think they will